# Codeigniter input library not recognising ajax post data

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post, input

I am trying to build a file manager with CodeIgniter and bootstrap modal (as my popup for the file manager on a button click) where I list folders and files from a directory. Although the first load of the modal loaded the subfolders and files of the specific directory. This happened when I used `.load()` function for the very first time as an ajax call and I want to load the subfolders files and folders on click a specific subfolder but it's just like I am making a lot of mistakes that the Codeigniter input is not returned mine ajax request post data. I have tried a lot of ajax pattern but not successful. I even used `print_r($_POST);` but return empty array

Here are my codes:

**Bootstrap Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade chivins_media" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable modal-lg" style="max-width: 87% !important;">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="media-buttons float-left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/icon/svg/folder (1).svg'); ?>" alt="Upload files"></a></li>
                            <li>+ New Folder</li>
                            <li>Move</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
                            <div class="card mb-4 border scrollbar border-warning" id="style-1">

                                <div class="card-body row force-overflow media-box" style="overflow: scroll; height: 550px">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**Jquery Ajax Code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var site_url = $('body').attr('data-site-url');

            $(".chivins_media").on("show.bs.modal", function(event)
            {

                $(this).find(".media-box").load(site_url+'medias', function() 
                {

                    files_on_click()
                    load_folder();


                    function load_folder() {

                        $('.media-folder').click(function(event) {

                            var path = $(this).attr('data-folder-path'),
                                post_data = {'path': path};

                            $.ajax({
                                url: site_url+"medias/folderitems/",
                                type: 'post',
                                cache: false,
                                data: {p: path},
                                success: function(data) 
                                {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    $(this).parents('.media-box').html(data);
                                    files_on_click();
                                    load_folder();
                                },
                                error: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            });


                            // do the ajax bit


                            // $.post('ajax_get_preview', post_data, function(theResponse){

                            //     // load the modal window with the relevant content returned
                            //     $('#modal-content').html(theResponse);
                            // });

                            // $.post(site_url+"medias/folderitems/", post_data, function(data){ 
                            //     alert(data);
                            // }, "html");

                        });
                    }

                    function files_on_click() 
                    {
                        var files = [];

                        $(".media-file").click(function(event)
                        {
                            var media_id = $(this).find('img').attr('data-file');
                            if ($(this).hasClass('selected-media')) {
                                $(this).removeClass('selected-media');
                                files.splice(files.indexOf(media_id),1); 
                            } 
                            else {
                                $(this).addClass('selected-media');
                                files.push( media_id );
                            }

                            // console.log( files );
                        });

                    }
                });

            });


        });
```

here is my controller code

**Controller**

```
    public function index()
        {

            $data = $this->media_manager->scan_dir();

            echo $this->media_builder($data);
        }

        public function folderitems()
        {

            // print_r($this->input->post());

            print_r($_POST);
            //  $path = $this->input->get('path', true);
            //  $medias = $this->media_manager->scan_dir($path);

            // echo $this->mediabuilder($medias);
        }
```

I want to list a file and folders of a directory one after the other on button click

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: I can't find the buttons with class `.media-folder` and `.media-file`. So i'm guessing they are added dynamically with the ajax response. So after you added them you need to bind the click event again for them because they didn't existed when you tried to add them. The other option is to find an element that's not added dynamically and attach the main event to it with a sub selector eg: `$(".modal-body").on("click", ".media-file", function(event){...}` Try one of them and see if that works. (Also check the console network page if the request reaches the server and does it gives back anything)

Comment: Yes they are added dynamically to the page

Comment: Yes, they are added dynamically to the page. I have already called the functions back which is working but my bone of context is that when I click on the subfolder it returns error ajax error 301 without it submitting the ajax post data. When I try this ``` $this->input->post('p'); ``` or ``` $_POST ```, it returns empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone I think I have solved my problem through many trial and error but if you still have a better option still post it here.

I just did some adjustments to my code by encrypting a return value like `uploads/images/users` with base64_encode and then retrieve it with `var path = $(this).attr('data-folder-path');` then reajust my ajax load function. Below is my ajustments

**Jquery**

```
                function load_folder() {

                    $('.media-folder').click(function(event) {

                        var path = $(this).attr('data-folder-path');

                        $(this).parents('.media-box').load(site_url+"medias/folderitems/"+path, function(data){
                            files_on_click();
                            load_folder();
                        });

                    });
                }
```

**controller**

```
        public function folderitems()
        {
            $path = base64_decode($this->uri->segment(4));
            echo $path; // It returns uploads/images/users
        }
```

if you still have a better option post it. Thanks for your help